# virtuoso rdf subject html view generator

Tags: web-apps, html, rdf, linked-data, sparql

I'm looking for software that generates simple html views for all RDF subjects served by [virtuoso-opensource](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/).

## Requirements

- Generates html view for all RDF subjects at a sparql endpoint
- Free, preferably open source
- Works with virtuoso-opensource

## Examples of what I'm looking for are:

- [The dbpedia sparql endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql)
- [The unesco sparql endpoint](http://vocabularies.unesco.org/sparql-form/)

dbpedia also uses virtuoso so I'll take that as an example.
When I visit my endpoint localhost:8890/sparql it looks identical to dbpedia.
When I run a query the results are displayed in the same way.

But when I click on a link in the results table at my endpoint I get: 

`Error HTTP/1.1 404 File not found
The requested URL was not found    URI  = '/place/411'`

while in dbpedia I get a webpage, for example http://dbpedia.org/page/Abbasid_Caliphate.

I don't need something that complicated, a turtle view would work. e.g. https://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing

From [this blog post](https://www.topquadrant.com/2011/11/22/creating-a-topbraid-mobile-web-app-with-sparql-web-pages/) it looks like TopBraid might be able to do what I need, but it doesn't seem to be free or opensource.

Do you know what dbpedia uses to generate views for their URIs?
Or any tool that would generate html views for RDF URIs?

Answer (score 1):

Try Pubby: oldie but Goldie. http://wifo5-03.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/pubby/. Let us know how it goes

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for, thank you! Searching for pubby on github I found https://github.com/Data2Semantics/brwsr and since my project is using python I'm going to try that out first

Comment: Looks like I'm already stuck. I'm trying to install pubby 0.3.3.

I tried on both tomcat 7 and 8 with no luck. I'm on ubuntu 16.04.
I followed the instructions on http://wifo5-03.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/pubby/

  
```
sudo apt-get install tomcat8 tomcat8-docs tomcat8-admin  
sudo mkdir /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/pubby  
sudo cp -R pubby/webapp/* /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps
sudo systemctl start tomcat8
```

Tomcat is running fine. I can see pubby in manager and it looks like it's deployed,  
but when I visit http://localhost:8080/pubby I get a 404.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. Looks like you [can't add line breaks to comments -_-](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165268/line-breaks-not-working-in-comments)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the [Virtuoso Facet Browser](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtFacetBrowserInstallConfig).

It's main function is a search interface, but it exposes an endpoint `/describe` by default, which provides a html view of rdf subjects at a virtuoso sparql endpoint.